# Link another value to a textarea element when posting to use as an id [PHP]

Tags: php, html, mysql, server-side

I have been trying to figure out a way to do this for a couple hours now. So, I am creating a form that generates textarea tags for every 'client' I selected, this part is easy for me. My problem is linking each text area to the clients id I have created for them so when I post the textarea input to my database I can post their id with it as well. Are there any ideas to post a value with each textarea? Any help is greatly appreciated...

MY html code for textarea

```
<td><?php echo "<textarea name='comments[]' cols='10'> </textarea>"?></td>
```

I TRY to post the text through a `foreach` loop, one by one

The variable holding the info I need is wrapped up like this

`<?php $clientlevel = $client.":".$i;?>`

I then use `explode()` to parse it

Comment: You have not really posted sufficient code - for instance how do you post the information? Do you post ALL the textareas at once or each one individually?

Comment: @RamRaider I post one by one through a foreach loop

Comment: can you show us the structure of the variable containing the client data?

Comment: @PaulH I have just added what I think you're asking for

Comment: Is this just an exercise or is it for a real site? In other words, does it have to be secured against manipulation of client id?

Comment: @PaulH a real site

Comment: @PaulH does it matter if it's real or exercise? If someone does an insecure job *as an exercise* it's only a matter of time before these bad habits cross over to genuine real-world jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pseudo code to show how you might assign the client id to each textarea and then process the POSTed data..

```
/* query the db using preferred methods */
$sql='select * from users where selected=1';
$res=$db->query($sql);

echo "<form method='post'>";
$i=0;
/* loop through recordset to generate textareas with client id assigned to comment */
while( $rs = $db->fetch($res) ){
    $uid=$rs->userid;
    echo "<td><textarea col=50 rows=3 name='comments[\"{$uid}\"]'>Comments.. $i</textarea></td>";
    $i++;
}
echo "<input type='submit'></form>";

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
    echo '<div>', print_r($_POST,true), '</pre>';


    /* specifically target and process the comments */
    $comments=!empty( $_POST['comments'] ) ? $_POST['comments'] : false;
    if( $comments ){
        foreach( $comments as $uid => $text ){
            echo 'User: '.$uid.' Comment:'.$text.'<br />';
        }
    }
}



Will output something like:
Array
(
    [comments] => Array
        (
            ["client_1"] => Comments.. 0
            ["client_2"] => Comments.. 1
            ["client_3"] => Comments.. 2
            ["client_4"] => Comments.. 3
            ["client_5"] => Comments.. 4
            ["client_6"] => Comments.. 5
            ["client_7"] => Comments.. 6
            ["client_8"] => Comments.. 7
            ["client_9"] => Comments.. 8
            ["client_10"] => Comments.. 9
        )

)
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not what I am looking for. I might have been unclear. I want to retrieve the comment in php and also retrieve their id to use in a mysql statement..

Comment: @LearningCODE, but you can do exactly that with this. i.e. `foreach ($_POST[comments] as $userId => $commentText) { ... // dbLookup with $userId ... }`. If you `var_dump($_POST['comments']);` you will see that  all the information you require is there.

Comment: @LearningCODE - you can iterate through that to get the user id and the associated comment

Comment: I apologize, I used this method and it worked flawlessly. I forgot to give you a one up and best answer. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you want ... but maybe that...

```
<td>
    <?php 
    echo "
<textarea name='comments[$id_client][]' cols='10'></textarea>";
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: What does this achieve? How can I access that in post? Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your help!

Comment: If get the "comments" key on $_POST var you will get a array with all comments posted sorted by id_client. So if you want get the comments posted by specific client you should do that: $comments = $_POST["comments"]; $comments_client_id_one = $comments["1"];

Ok, i've not said that "id_client" must be the var which contains the id_client, so the right way is: 

 <td><?php echo "<textarea name='comments[$id_client][]' cols='10'> </textarea>"?></td>

Comment: When I try to access $comments["1"], I get nothing... but $comments["0"] holds my comment.

Comment: Of course, the index will be the same of client/s you post, don't forget that you are setting the index of array $comments with $id_client var. If you submit a comment of client with id 53, the points access will be $comments["53"], if you submit comments of client 33, 44 and 6 at the same time you will find the comments of client 33 on $comments["33"], 44 client's comments on $comments["44"], etc...

Comment: Oh, no i want to be able to post their id, not use it as an index.... for example if someones id is 100710, I want to be able to retrieve that number so I can use it when I am inputting comments in mysql by id.

Comment: Just store the id on $_SESSION var when a client log in... You will be able to access it from every point of your web site.

Comment: This is not for users to login...... This is evaluation software, I have a list of people I evaluate them at the same time, each user has a comment box where I can write notes, I want to be able to post these comments and link them up with their id

Comment: So, how you assign an id to each one if they never log in? Random number ?